# Enable pinch to zoom and click on div for PhoneGap application for both iOS and Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I need to **enable pinch to zoom** feature for both iOS and Android in **PhoneGap** application for specific div element also i want **click event** on that div.

I already used 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />`

but not working fine.

Anyone can suggest me any answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys [iScroll5](http://iscrolljs.com/#zoom) helps me to solve this issue. 
I used following property to solve my problem

`myScroll = new IScroll('#wrapper', {
    zoom: true,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollY: true,
    mouseWheel: true,
    wheelAction: 'zoom',
    click:true
});`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [hammerJS](http://hammerjs.github.io/) for this kind of uses, it is very tested and it is going to avoid you estranges behaviors